# how can I right different responsives in html and css

Tags: html, css, responsive

Hey guys I wrote 6 different responsive for my page but it just read one of my styles for all of them and other 5 styles don't work at all.

I'd be glad if you could help me

Comment: The question is very vague. Have you tried using media queries?

Comment: yes i did and they worked but for example when i wrote styles for iPhone 6  my styles for galaxy S5 don't work

Comment: Ok can you please show the code?

Comment: @media only  screen and (max-width: 1025px) and (max-height: 1367px) {

    .header {
        width: 90%;  }

Comment: @media  only screen and (max-width: 769px) and (max-height: 1025px) {

    .header {
        width: 100%;
      
    }

Comment: First one work and second one dont. By the way they are on separate css files

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1025px) and (min-height: 1366px) and (max-height: 1367px) {
 .header { width: 90%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 769px) and (min-height: 1024px) and (max-height: 1025px) {
 .header { width: 100%; }
}
```